# Ruby class declaration question

Tags: ruby

Can't i do it like this:

```
class Hardware

before_filter

  def before_filter
    puts "ge"
  end

end
```

It says before_filter is undefined method or variable when I instantiate it

```
hd = Hardware.new
```

because ive seen others put a method name in a class before. Just wondering how it works. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two problems with your code:

1. You are calling a *class* method, but your are defining an *instance* method.
2. You are calling the method *before* it has been defined.

Both of these obviously cannot work.

This would work:

```
class Hardware
  def self.before_filter
    puts "ge"
  end

  before_filter
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify: `before_filter` would get called more or less as soon as it is read, unlike other languages that read everything first and then executes the code. That kind of thing also means you can't write a class and then write the module you want it to include.

Answer (score 5):

`before_filter` is an ActiveRecord class method (see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)) and so would only be available if your model inherited from `ActiveRecord::Base` (or a subclass). Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

You might just be looking for:

```
class Hardware
  def initialize
    super
    before_filter
  end

  protected
  def before_filter
    # ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Either change

```
def before_filter
```

to

```
def self.before_filter
```

and call it after defined

OR

Comment `before_filter`

```
class Hardware
  def before_filter
    puts "ge"
  end
end
```

and Call like

```
hd = Hardware.new
hd.before_filter
```